# Javascript - How is var making a difference?

Tags: javascript, var

See the below snippets. 
First one errors out, which is expected. 
Second one passes. What is the reason, or difference between the two snippets.

```
var myvar = 4,7 //Error

myvar2 = 3,4 //No error
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first line, you are separating declaration by comma ([Variable Statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)), here is missing a variable name.

The second line is using the [Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), which works fine, even there is no need for it.

The question arised

> If second was a comma operator, then the value in myvar2 would be 4. but it is 3!

It is because of the [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) of comma versus equal. The assignment is made and the comma is evaluated later.

Comment: I would say that the 1st one is [the variable statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) having special syntax which is violated in the given code.

Comment: @Nina Scholz - If second was a comma operator, then the value in myvar2 would be 4. but it is 3!

Answer (score 2):

The first line basically translates to this:

```
var myvar = 4,
7
```

So the "second line" throws the error because the JavaScript intepreter expects you want to assign two variables but cannot find a name for the second one. For example you could assign your variables like this

```
var first = 0,
    obj = {},
    s = "my string",
    array = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

Without getting an error since it is valid JavaScript and every value has a variable name it can be assigned to.

In the second example you are only assigning the last number - without the  `var` keyword JavaScript does not throw an error and just assigns the first value. It is kind of like writing the following

```
myvar = 3
4
```

So the first value is assigned. I previously mixed this up (see history). When passing `myvar = 3,4` to the console it looks like 4 would be assigned, however it is just printed into the console - in other words the part behind the `,` is evaluated. You can see this when you paste the following into the console

```
myvar = 3, _this_function_doesnt_exist()
```

Here the parser will throw an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: _this_function_doesnt_exist is not defined(…)` - the previous expression (`myvar = 3`) is still executed so `myvar` will be 3.

I used to write all my variables with only one `var` keyword but found it rather confusing and ugly. In general I advice to use one assignment per line and `var` in front of every variable (or `const`, `let`, etc. if you write ECMAScript 2015/ES6)

Comment: Its not the second value that gets assigned, its the first value itself!

Comment: Kevin you can check and see that the first number is assigned not the second one in the working example, you need to correct your answer in order to avoid confussion

Comment: I am sorry, you are right. The second value gets printed to the console but the first one gets assigned! I will update my answer.

Comment: So I updated my answer to correct my mistaken assumption and give an explanation of what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand a bit further on `Nina Schloz` answer

```
 var myvar = 4, 7 // throws Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

 // Because declared variables are hoisted to the top of the scope,this translates to
 /*
    var myvar;
    var 7; // throws Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
    myvar = 4; // this never gets executed
 */

 var anotherVar = 4, x; // this doesn't throw an error
 // this translates to
 /*
    var anotherVar;
    var x;
    anotherVar=4;
 */
```

When we do `myvar2=3,4` we are using `comma operator` which first assigns 3 to an `undeclared variable myvar2` and then returns last value of expression (from left to right) which is number 4